# Column Chart issues

Tags: javascript, highcharts

For 10 and 1.0 in series data. The graph columns are plotting in same length. where am I making mistakes?

I have written this code to generate Bar chart. Last column is displaying wrongly.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text

Comment: Please reproduce your issue with the sample data on some online editor.